# Porcelain toilet on porcelain tile?

Tags: bathroom

Should my porcelain toilet sit directly on the porcelain tile I am installing?  Or should I use a cushion of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our house the toilets are directly on the porcelain tile with no pad. One toilet rocked and required plastic wedges to stop the rocking. These wedges are made specifically for toilets.